# N-th element of a list

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog. How to get n-th element of a list when a list starts from 1 (index) ? How can I transform this, which gets n-th element, but list starts from 0 index.

```
   element_at(X,[X|_],1).
   element_at(X,[_|L],K) :- element_at(X,L,K1), K is K1 + 1.
```

Comment: I don't see the issue. The predicate you show already gives the 1-based index of `X` in the list. For a 0-based index, the base case would be, `element_at(X, [X|_], 0).`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your index is relative to 0, 1 or some other number is irrelevant. It's the same code — the only difference is your arbitrary starting value.

This produces indices relative to zero:

```
element0( [X|_] , 0 , X ) .
element0( [_|L] , N , X ) :- element0(L,T,X) , N is T+1 .
```

Change the first clause produces indices relative to one:

```
element1( [X|_] , 1 , X ) .
element1( [_|L] , N , X ) :- element1(L,T,X) , N is T+1 .
```

This produce indices relative to `-97`:

```
element97( [X|_] , -97 , X ) .
element97( [_|L] , N   , X ) :- element97(L,T,X) , N is T+1 .
```

Once you have those, you can run them and get

```
?- element0( [a,b,c] , N , X ).
N = 0 , X = a ;
N = 1 , X = b ;
N = 2 , X = c ;
false.

?- element1( [a,b,c] , N , X ).
N = 1 , X = a ;
N = 2 , X = b ;
N = 3 , X = c ;
false.

?- element97([a,b,c],N,X).
N = -97 , X = a ;
N = -96 , X = b ;
N = -95 , X = c ;
false.
```

One should note, though, that this will work generatively as well:

```
?- element0(L,N,a).
```

will, produce an near-infinite set of results (at least until your stack overflows), with L and N bound to lists with the atom `a` at the respective positions:

```
N = 0 , L = [ a                                              | _G3045 ] ;
N = 1 , L = [ _G3044 , a                                     | _G3048 ] ;
N = 2 , L = [ _G3044 , _G3047 , a                            | _G3051 ] ;
N = 3 , L = [ _G3044 , _G3047 , _G3050 , a                   | _G3054 ] ;
N = 4 , L = [ _G3044 , _G3047 , _G3050 , _G3053 , a          | _G3057 ] ;
N = 5 , L = [ _G3044 , _G3047 , _G3050 , _G3053 , _G3056 , a | _G3060 ] ;
...
```

That's the way prolog works.

Comment: maybe a bug ? `element1( [_|L] , N , X ) :- element0(L,T,X) ,` should be `element0( [_|L] , N , X ) :- element0(L,T,X) ,`. Also this other is suspicious `element97( [_|L] , N   , X ) :- element1(L,T,X),`

Answer (score 0):

There are standard predicates `nth1/3` and `nth0/3` that do what you want:

```
?- nth1(1, [1, 2, 3], X).
X = 1.

?- nth0(1, [1, 2, 3], X).
X = 2.
```